# beta invite code + codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, beta-testing

I'd like to limit access to my app (in Codeigniter) for beta users. Wondering if anyone knows of a library, spark or other option that can help me get started.

Would prefer not to reinvent the wheel if there's something out there already. My searches on Google and other resources haven't yielded anything.

Comment: There are as many ways to let users access your beta apps, as there _are_ beta apps. You need to be more specific about what behavior you're looking for.

Comment: I didn't ask for ways--I asked for LIBRARIES. There are numerous questions on SO that ask this very same question for RoR, Django, and other frameworks--and they have plenty of responses. CI doesn't appear to have many current libraries that do this, hence my question. If you don't know of any, don't worry about it.

Comment: where is your app hosted? cross browser or in-house ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ANY of the Authentication libraries - and add a field called "Beta Code" on the registration page. If "beta code = your secret beta code" then allow registration. If the code is incorrect, then dont allow them to sign up.

You could extend if further when you are ready to go live, and turn it into a "promotion code", and if code = X, then apply 10% discount, extra free time etc (if this is a paid service when you go live).

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. You know, this is such a perfect, simple answer, but I couldn't see it! I've been logging alot of hours on other programming issues with the app, I didn't have any more capacity to think through this--just couldn't see it. Appreciate your response.